# reloadOptionLabels is remove on easylife switcher

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I have installed an extension simple product pricing but it doesn't work accordingly and the support said that the easylife switcher remove the `reloadOptionLabels` from `product.js`.

I do not know how to contact the easylife switcher and any solution from you guys is much appreciated.

here's the function for `reloadOptionLabels`

```
reloadOptionLabels: function(element){
        var selectedPrice;
        if(element.options[element.selectedIndex].config){
            selectedPrice = parseFloat(element.options[element.selectedIndex].config.price)
        }
        else{
            selectedPrice = 0;
        }
        for(var i=0;i<element.options.length;i++){
            if(element.options[i].config){
                element.options[i].text = this.getOptionLabel(element.options[i].config, element.options[i].config.price-selectedPrice);
            }
        }
    },
```

but i cant make it since the getOptionLabel had $supper param.

```
getOptionLabel : function($super, option, price) {
        if (this.getConfigValue(this.config, 'show_added_prices', false)) {
            return $super(option, price);
        }
        return option.label;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAK easylife_switcher does not remove any functions from product.js it does override some methods and add new ones.

The `$super` param you refer to is [prototype](http://prototypejs.org/)'s internal way of overriding methods and can be fully ignored by the final producer. i.e. `getOptionLabel : function($super, option, price) {...}` is meant to be called with TWO arguments. The `$super` is simply a way for the new function to access the parent's method, similar to php`s`parent::getOptionLabel($myOption, $myPrice)`. see [docs](http://prototypejs.org/learn/class-inheritance) for further info.

So further debugging is needed.

When you load the page in the browser. Does the javascript console show any errors? (on most browsers press `F12` for the dev tools)